# Blazor Server: GraphServiceClient services for both App and User scopes

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Blazor Server App where users Authenticate using AzureAD domain credentials.
In startup I register MicrosoftGraph service for DI use.

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(config.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
  .AddMicrosoftGraph(config.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
  .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I can inject a **GraphServiceClient** on any page and query the Microsoft Graph.
However, this seems to only respect the User scopes and not Application level scopes.

In addition to being able to query the MsGraph as the user, I'd like to also be able to register a **GraphServiceClient** that can query the Graph using scopes that have been granted to the **Application**. What am I missing?